# How to make Python calculate result of percentage?

Tags: python, calculator, percentage

I want Python to be able to the calculate the result of a percentage.

For example: If a drink costs 8, calculate what it costs with 20% added tips (or whatever given percentage).

It then should be 9.6 of course. I thought I might be able to do it with code something like this:

```
drink = 8 + 20%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't support expressing percentages with the `%` symbol. It can multiply, however.

Increasing a value by 20% means multiplying it by 1.2.

```
drink = 8 * 1.2
```

You could write a function if you want to give the percentage and derive the factor:

```
def add_tips(value, percentage):
    return value * (1 + percentage / 100)
```

```
>>> drink = 8
>>> add_tips(drink, 20)
9.6
```

The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 1):

You can always translate percentages to a floating-point value like `20% = 0.2` or `81.7% = 0.817`. So simply divide by `100` to transform percentage to floating-point number. In your case, you want to add `20%` of a number to this number aka you want `120%` of this number which equates to multiplying with `1.2`. You can also validate this by calculating `8 + (8 * 0.2)` which might be more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Given the original cost and percentage, you can do this to get the total amount.

```
totalCost = cost + (percentage/100)*cost
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does support the *expression* of percentages, thanks to the **str format()**. If you like, you can even mimic that behavior in a unittest.

Example code:

```
def divideby4(x):
    return "{0:.0%}".format(x/4)
```

Example test:

```
import unittest
import some_silly_calc

class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):
... 

    def test_divide(self):
        result = some_silly_calc.divideby4(2)
        self.assertEqual(result, "{0:.0%}".format(.50))
```

Alternative method if you don't want to use "%":

```
def divideby4(x):
    return (x / 4 * 100)
```

I love how much Python 3+ has evolved since Python 2.7. So many cool features! HTH :)